# Should I use React.memo on my chat app or not?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a chat app. I memo this. Is that bad for chat apps because every time comes new mesasges

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, and honestly probably needs more specifics to have a concrete answer.

If there are scenarios where your chat app may be re-rendered in a way that ends up being the same as it was pre-re-render, then using React.memo could result in a performance boost.

React.memo will still check for changes in its props, and attempt to re-render when those are changed.

If you have more specific questions, let me know.

Comment: You can upload images, videos, you can select an chat to delete them, so every time I select an chat item I set a new state to get the current chat id.